# ¿Como obtener el texto de un JButton? [Java]

Tags: java, botón

No puedo compilar mi programa ya que, al momento de compilar, lanza el siguiente error:

```
boletosAutobus.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
     String nombre = btn.getText().toString();
                        ^
   symbol: method getText()
   location: variable btn of type Button
1 error
```

El objetivo de mi práctica es un simulador de boletos de autobús en el que tengo que acumular en un `String` el valor de los botones para saber cuáles están siendo ocupados y cuántos libres.

Estuve buscando la forma de hacerlo y, según vi en distintos foros, lo hacen de esta manera pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar. Si pongo `getName()` sí me sale el valor del botón pero no puedo usarlo como `int`

```
public class boletosAutobus extends Frame implements ActionListener {

    Button botones[]=new Button[45];
    Button boton2;
    Label disponibilidad=new Label("***************");
    int turno=0;
    
    public boletosAutobus(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4,11));
        for(int i=0; i<44; i++){
            add(botones[i]=new Button(""+i));
            botones[i].addActionListener(this);
            botones[i].setBackground(Color.green);
        }
        add(boton2 = new Button("ver"));
        setSize(700, 500); setVisible(true);
        add(disponibilidad);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Button btn=(Button)e.getSource();
        String nombre = btn.getText().toString();
        btn.setLabel("R");
        btn.setBackground(Color.red);
        btn.setEnabled(false);
        System.out.println(nombre);
    }
    
    public static void main(String s[]){ 
        new boletosAutobus(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: La clase Button no tiene un método getText(). Seguramente lo que buscas es [`getLabel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html#getLabel())

Comment: Si el problema es convertirlo a int puedes hacer `Integer.parseInt(btn.getName().toString());`

Comment: Aparte, hacer ' add(botones[i]=new Button(""+i));' es poco optimo, mejor `add(botones[i]=new Button(String.valueOf(i)));`

Comment: gracias gracias a sus comentarios voy intentar implementar lo que me dijeron gracias amigos.

Answer (score -1):

Es un poco extraño pero creo que si quieres obtener el texto del boton al ser presionado prueba  con esto:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
// Listener del btn
Button b = (Button)v;
String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
```

}

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: La clase Button no tiene `getText()`

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero cheque la api de oracle oficial y si no tiene el metodo getText pero de igual forma gracias amigo